# Is there a way in R to group by 'runs'?

Tags: r

Say I have:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-13"),
               want_group=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3,3,3,4))
```

I want to create a want_group variable that groups by date, group, and whether they were "daily". So for example I want to create unique id's for within group 1 for the 1st and 2nd, and then a new unique id for the 4th and 5th, and then similarly for group 2 for the 9th, 10th, and 11th.

```
  group       date want_group
1     1 2000-01-01          1
2     1 2000-01-02          1
3     1 2000-01-04          2
4     1 2000-01-05          2
5     2 2000-01-09          3
6     2 2000-01-10          3
7     2 2000-01-11          3
8     2 2000-01-13          4
```

Thanks,

Comment: is `want_group` in your original `df` the exact output you want?

Comment: could be character, I'm not picky. Just any way to categorize the "runs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `diff` and `cumsum` to calculate the runs. This increments everytime the difference in `date` is more than 1.

```
df$new <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(df$date)) > 1))
df

#  group       date want_group new
#1     1 2000-01-01          1   1
#2     1 2000-01-02          1   1
#3     1 2000-01-04          2   2
#4     1 2000-01-05          2   2
#5     2 2000-01-09          3   3
#6     2 2000-01-10          3   3
#7     2 2000-01-11          3   3
#8     2 2000-01-13          4   4
```

We add `TRUE` in the beginning since `diff` returns output of length 1 less than the original vector.

---

To handle this by group we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(new = c(TRUE, diff(date) > 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(new = cumsum(new))
```

Comment: Does this work also if say there was group=3 with the exact same dates as group 1? I would want the “new” to have different, unique ids for another group even if they share dates with another group

Comment: @biostatguy12 okay, updated the answer to handle it by group.

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can also do

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$new <- with(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, date[-1]- date[-length(date)] > 1)))
df$new
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

---

Or use difference with `lag` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), 
        want_group = cumsum(date - lag(date, default = first(date)) > 1))
```